# Flutter: How to avoid rerender when using custom object as Getx Observable

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I have a model class called `Todo` and which has fields like these

```
class Todo{
 String name;
 String note;
 DateTime date;
 String color;
 bool isDone;
}
```

And I have a controller called `TodoController` in which I make `Todo` observable

```
class TodoController extends GetxController{
  final Todo = Todo().obs;
}
```

All the fields (name, date etc.) have their own widget to display and edit them, but problem is whenever I edit one field all other build method of other fields also get called.

```
todo.update((todo) {
    todo.name = nameController.text;
});
```

The other way is I can make every field observable instead of making the whole object observable, but that is too cumbersome. Anyone have any other workaround for this?

Comment: I think making every field observable is the only way

Answer (score 0):

Don't give the models .obs but give it to the list that will contain all the data of todo model. For example `var todoList = [].obs` or whatever variables that will contai  your todo model